# Cannot call Web API in different project but same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-web-api

here is my situation. I have **1 solution** containing **2 projects**: Web API and Web Form. I set **both projects as Startup projects**. In the code behind, I call the Web API like this:

```
private HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile(int id)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8096/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/pdf"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/document/" + id).Result;
        return response;
    }
}
```

When I click Start in Visual Studio, if the Web API is running on **different port** from WebForm, it will "actively refused the connection" (as the exception said).

So my question is: how can I make Web API accept the call **without changing its port**? I don't want both projects to run on the same port. Why can't I call it normally as I usually do with many external APIs?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should call it by project reference in place of webapi.. for eg. webmethod call from reference project in same solution..

Comment: I think you check your API URL in your browser and also check Both project are running

Comment: @Shirish: I want to call it by giving a link :)

Comment: @manish: yes, I can call the API from my browser, and everything is running normally.

Comment: @Forte_201092 you can call webmethod on link click. it is same process..

Comment: You mean I should add reference to the Web API and call its function like how we add the third party library and use it? No, I don't think we should do that because it's not encapsulation. For example, I do authentication for every request to Web API.